# Style download link <a> after download?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I change the download link color after it was downloaded?
I tried with the visited attribute, but it doesn't work (it do work only with regular links and not with download docs):

Thanks

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/someFile.csv" target="_blank">
    http://example.com/files/someFile.csv
</a>
```

with the visited style:

```
a:visited {
    color: pink;
}
```

Comment: HTML nor CSS do never know when the user actually downloaded something. There is now ay in finding out if a download as actually be made. All it can track is, if a download has been clicked upon / visited.

Comment: `:visited` works based on history entries, but I suppose such a download link does not create an actual history entry to begin with. So if the browser is not keeping track of this for you, then your only option is to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As other pointed out, in order to have the `:visited` work properly, you have to create an history entry for that link. One way to do this would be to add a `target="_blank"` attribut to your link. This will make the link open in another page, which will create an history entry.

The stackoverflow embedded snipet won't let you open a new window directly, so you have to ctrl+click on the link. This won't happen on a real page.

Also, **PLEASE NOTE** that the snippet link **WILL DOWNLOAD AN ACTUAL FILE** taken from https://file-examples.com. Be aware of that before clicking the link.

```css
a:visited {
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/storage/2017/02/file-sample_1MB.doc" target="_blank">
https://file-examples.com/wp-content/storage/2017/02/file-sample_1MB.doc
</a>
```

Comment: this will show that somebody visited the link not that he necessarily downloaded the file

Comment: I'm not aware of any way the Javascript can know if you've actually downlaoded a file. But the download will be automatically triggered when loading the new page, so it's reasonable to assume the file was downloaded.

Comment: still not working for me... also with the target="_blank"

Comment: It's working fine for me in the provided snippet, when I ctrl+click the link. Maybe it's an issue with your browser. Have you tried in another browser ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, HTML or CSS do not know if something is actualy downloaded or not. You can only detect that the link was clicked upon, and according to that add some class which will show that it was used. For that you can use javascript, for example with jQuery this could look like this:

`$("a.download").click(function(){ $(this).addClass("downloaded"); });`

```
a.downloaded { color:pink;}
```

If you want to make things persistant accross page reloads, you could use browser localStorage and save the id of the anchor that needs to be marked as downloaded file, and on page load use that `a#id` to set the class again to downloaded.